# EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) in some ipad models

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am encountering some strange behaviors with an app that I'm developing. When I test it in Xcode it works fine -  no errors or warnings! It worked ok being distributed as ad-hoc too! After it was submitted to the App Store and got approved without any problems, I downloaded it onto my iPad 2 and it worked fine.

But the client tells me that the app crashes on iPad 4th generation and iPad Air.

I was in the client's office and I tested it with their iPad 4 generation. I deleted and downloaded it again from the store and nothing, it still crashes! Then, I tested directly in Xcode and to my surprise the app runs with no errors! After deleting the Xcode build version and downloading it again from the App Store, it ran *without crashing*.

Below is the log that I caught from another device that crashed too.

Someone have an idea about this problem? Thank you for any information!

```
Incident Identifier: 1E40E435-42BE-448F-AD73-B596B0F24FD7
CrashReporter Key:   199c1d309e448e9f4ec2266b87510c50a18ca49a
Hardware Model:      iPad4,2
Process:             myapp [3498]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/7D97FBDC-5EAB-4186-BEE7-5C102A1243F2/myapp.app/myapp
Identifier:          com.domain.myapp
Version:             1.1.0 (1.1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-08-25 10:40:51.033 -0300
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3938f1f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x393f77b3 pthread_kill + 55
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3933fff5 abort + 73
3   myapp                           0x000541eb -[AppDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] (AppDelegate.m:205)
4   myapp                           0x00053cdd -[AppDelegate managedObjectContext] (AppDelegate.m:118)
5   myapp                           0x0006d70b -[Atualizacao facebookInstallAd] (Atualizacao.m:33)
6   myapp                           0x0006ce3f -[StartViewController copyStartFiles] (StartViewController.m:120)
7   Foundation                      0x2ebe4113 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 411
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2e1cff4d __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 13
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2e1cfb67 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 791
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2e1cdeef __CFRunLoopRun + 1215
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2e138765 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2e138547 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
13  GraphicsServices                0x3306f6cf GSEventRunModal + 135
14  UIKit                           0x30a9788d UIApplicationMain + 1133
15  myapp                           0x00051edf main (main.m:16)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x392d8ab5 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3937c804 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x392cb051 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 229
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x392c52df _dispatch_mgr_thread + 35

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3938fc70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x393f4c1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x393f4ad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3938fc70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x393f4c1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x393f4ad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3937caa0 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x392c9d3d _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 173
2   MediaToolbox                    0x2f6578cb fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 1751
3   CoreMedia                       0x2e768161 figThreadMain + 193
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x393f6957 _pthread_body + 139
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x393f68c7 _pthread_start + 99
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x393f4ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3938fc70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x393f4c1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x393f4ad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000306
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3b07c18c      r6: 0x146826d0      r7: 0x27db7b40
    r8: 0x0000000c    r9: 0x3b07ce30     r10: 0x1465cba0     r11: 0x1465a680
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27db7b34      lr: 0x393f77b7      pc: 0x3938f1f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

**EDIT** - About the "trojanfoe" question

`-[AppDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] (AppDelegate.m:205)` commented bellow.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
        NSURL *preloadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"databaseStart" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
        NSError* err = nil;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:preloadURL toURL:storeURL error:&err];
        [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:storeURL];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        abort(); // line 205
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: What's at `AppDelegate.m:205` then?

Comment: trojanfoe - i included in the post the code that have the line 205 of AppDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "crash" is self-inflicted and is due to calling `abort()` which should only be used when  the idea of living any longer is too much for the process to consider.

In this particular case you are calling a method that *can* fail (most can) and you need to handle this more gracefully:

1. Report the error, that is returned, using `NSLog()` or a logging framework like [Cocoa Lumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack) as this will help you diagnose future issues.
2. Return `nil` rather than aborting.  If your app cannot continue because of this issue you will need to make it sit inside some sort of "cannot continue" window, preferably containing a relevant error message allowing the user to *electively* terminate the app.

Comment: @PauloSigales You need to see what's in that `NSError` object when it fails.

Comment: The problem is that this happens when i downloaded from apple store and only in some ipad models. I delete, download again and crash, later I tryed debug one of these models and works in xcode and after debug in xcode i tryed download again from store and work too!

Comment: The error just happens with published versions. When i test in xcode or make a ad-hoc, the problem not happens.

Comment: Which is where the logging comes into it.

Comment: I think i found the solution with your comments ... when i send the last update i change some itens in database. In http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657 the spoke about migration, but i not have the old version. If i change the name of model and sql i think its will force the app to use the new model. Right?

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid.  You'll have to ask another question about that.

Comment: Just for others people know ... I change the name and work =)

Comment: @PauloSigales You changed the name of what? Please explain exactly how you solved this.

Comment: @cocoanutmobile i change the name of coredata model file (xcdatamodeld) and respectives in - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel and - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator.